# Book series my dad told me about. It involves space travel, clones, and an indigenous people with kangaroo tails

Tags: story-identification, books, clones, mind-uploading

My dad read a book series that he recommended to me last year. Now that I am ready to start it, neither of us can recall the title. He said there were several in the series but he can't recall how many.

The book is about traveling to a new planet, presumably with the goal of colonizing it. The crew are clones who have no memory. I think the goal was for the older original versions of the clones to transfer their consciousness into the clone bodies to be able to live on the new planet but something goes wrong.

There is an indigenous species on the planet who are humanoid but have kangaroo like tails.

The clone crew has markings on them that they don't understand until late. Apparently they are markings to indicate status or role on the new world. The person who they voted as there leader, it turns out, is marked as a servant or slave class.

Comment: There is a Poul Anderson novel [Question and Answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_and_Answer_(novel)) with aliens described as *They stood on their hind legs like men, though with a forward slant which reduced their potential one and three fourths-meter height by a good ten centimeters; a heavy kangaroolike tail balanced the body, and was probably a wicked weapon for infighting.* But there is no mention of clones in this book.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

My dad found it: [The Generations Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/154480-the-generations-trilogy) by Scott Sigler:

- [*Alive*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23278532-alive) (2015)

  > *I open my eyes to darkness. Total darkness. I hear my own breathing, but nothing else. I lift my head…it thumps against something solid and unmoving. There is a board right in front of my face. No, not a board…a lid.*
  >
  > A teenage girl awakens to find herself trapped in a coffin. She has no idea who she is, where she is, or how she got there. Fighting her way free brings little relief—she discovers only a room lined with caskets and a handful of equally mystified survivors. Beyond their room lies a corridor filled with bones and dust, but no people…and no answers.
  >
  > She knows only one thing about herself—her name, M. Savage, which was engraved on the foot of her coffin—yet she finds herself in charge. She is not the biggest among them, or the boldest, but for some reason the others trust her. Now, if they’re to have any chance, she must get them to trust one another.
  >
  > Whatever the truth is, she is determined to find it and confront it. If she has to lead, she will make sure they survive. Maybe there's a way out, a rational explanation, and a fighting chance against the dangers to come. Or maybe a reality they cannot comprehend lies just beyond the next turn.
- [*Alight*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25489021-alight) (2016)

  > *“If it’s war they want, they messed with the wrong girl.”*
  >
  > M. Savage—or Em, as she is called—has made a bewildering and ominous discovery. She and the other young people she was chosen to lead awoke in strange coffins with no memory of their names or their pasts. They faced an empty, unknown place of twisting tunnels and human bones. With only one another to depend on, they searched for answers and found the truth about their terrifying fate. Confronted by a monstrous enemy, they vowed never to surrender—and, by any means, to survive.
  >
  > The planet Omeyocan may be the sanctuary Em and her comrades seek. But the planet for which they were created turns out not to be a pristine, virgin world. Vestiges of a lost civilization testify to a horrifying past that may yet repeat itself. And when a new enemy creeps from the jungle shadows, Em and her young refugees learn there’s nowhere left to run. They face a simple choice: fight or die.
  >
  > In the midst of this desperate struggle, their unity is compromised from within—and a dangerous zealot devoted to a bloodthirsty god moves to usurp Em’s command, threatening to lead them all down a path to violent doom.
- [*Alone*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28227834-alone) (2017)

  > *“We thought this place was our destiny—not our doom.”*
  >
  > Pawns in a millennia-old struggle, the young people known only as the Birthday Children were genetically engineered to survive on the planet Omeyocan—but they were never meant to live there. They were made to be “overwritten,” their minds wiped and replaced by the consciousness of the monsters who created them.
  >
  > Em changed all of that.
  >
  > She unified her people and led a revolt against their creators. Em and her friends escaped an ancient ghost ship and fled to Omeyocan. They thought they would find an uninhabited paradise. Instead, they found the ruins of a massive city long since swallowed by the jungle. And they weren’t alone. The Birthday Children fought for survival against the elements, jungle wildlife, the “Grownups” who created them . . . and, as evil corrupted their numbers, even against themselves.
  >
  > With these opponents finally defeated, Em and her people realized that more threats were coming, traveling from across the universe to lay claim to their planet. The Birthday Children have prepared as best they can against this alien armada. Now, as the first ships reach orbit around Omeyocan, the final battle for the planet begins.

Comment: You should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: To expand on what Laurel said, merging your accounts will allow you to regain full ownership of that question, and then you'll be able to accept your own answer. Please do! This way, everyone will se the mystery was solved :) and if you can add a summary or some quotes that explain how it matched, it'd be even better!