# Sci-fi novel series with older people transferring their minds into younger bodies

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, mind-uploading

All I remember is that the premise is that these old people put their consciousness into younger bodies, and they all have different symbols on their bodies denoting their role in society. I think the main character is a girl who has the "empty" symbol. At some point they all wake up from their pods (they're in space but they don't find out until later in the book). I wanna say that there's one character named O'Malley who is the politician/diplomat role. The kids take over the ship at some point and land it on some planet (I think this is where the first book ends and the second begins?) It is a series and sorry that this is all I remember, it's bits and pieces but hopefully someone knows what it is...

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this, and roughly when do you think it might've been published? Also, can you remember what the covers of any of the books looked like?

Comment: I read it no more than 4 years ago (sorry if that's too big a timeline), it's a relatively recent book, at the very least it's gotta be 21st century. I don't remember the cover since I think I read it as an ebook, but it's ur run-of-the-mill sci fi book. Asked my friends and they said that it kinda reminded them of maze runner and divergent

Comment: the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203537/book-series-my-dad-told-me-about-it-involves-space-travel-clones-and-an-indig/203627#203627

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, it's [The Generations Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/154480-the-generations-trilogy) by [Scott Sigler](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?37119).

Comment: Well done. Please don't forget to mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: And also, if you can, psychics assume more details so that other people might find their answer when searching.

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer you are looking for, but matches the title question:

[The Annihilation of Foreverland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006S63JLM) by Tony Bertauski

And its sequels:

[Foreverland Is Dead](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D4GFD8G)

and:

[Ashes of Foreverland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UGTD7W8)

The series matches the premise: older rich people are (trying to) put their consciousnesses into the minds of children.

Where it does not match: the children are brutally treated in waking life and escape by willingly entering "Foreverland", a powerful mindscape reality where they appear to have lucid control, but are actually being subsumed by the minds of old people also linked into the dream world.

The protagonists vary by book and it is unclear how successful the mind transfer was (spoiler: it didn't entirely fail).